# Bash command in ruby script - Error "Command not found"

Tags: ruby, bash, command

I need to run a bash command (ls -al) in my ruby script.
This command is launched in different folders that start with the letters "my".

```
Dir.glob("#{PATH_TO_SEARCH}/my*",File::FNM_CASEFOLD) do |path|

    command = path + "/ls -al"
    output_result = (%x(#{command}))

end
```

I receive a strange error:

```
"command not found: /home/user/my123/ls -al"
"command not found: /home/user/my222/ls -al"
"command not found: /home/user/my423/ls -al"
```

The iteration goes well. The problem is the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generate your commands inproperly. It should be:

```
command = 'ls -al ' + path
```